# Amazon Pay in Alexa skill to order from Amazon

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, amazon-pay

I have developed an Alexa skill which recommends you the best products for household chores. Now I want to add Amazon pay in it to order products from amazon on behalf of user like:

**Alexa**: Ok! I recommend productABC available on amazon. would you like to order/buy it now?

**User**: Yes

My questions are:

Is this possible to order on **amazon** from alexa skill? and what requirements do i need to have?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in a custom skill to utilize pay with Amazon to purchase goods through Amazon. the [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/amazon-pay/alexa-amazon-pay-faq.html#what_is_Alexa_skills) Is to utilize Pay with Amazon as the way to tender a purchase that you design through a seller who has their own transaction mechanism. Alexa has as a native built-in ability a way to order goods from amazon.com. 
So the answer is no, you can utilize the skill or application that you create to sell electronic merchandise usable in the skill, or bonus material or additional content as an ISP but having the custom skill, order merchandise via your flow is not available.